# Ubuntu for android phone/tablet

Tags: android, tablet, smartphone

I have an android smartphone, Sony Xperia neo L, and an android tablet, Lenovo thinkpad tablet 1838-a19. Can I just change my OS to ubuntu, since the Sony Xperia don't have docking nor HDMI port?
If, I can change the OS from android to Ubuntu where did on earth I could download the instalation master file? And would you just give me any link to step-by-step ubuntu instalation over android.
thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xda-developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) does a lot of work to get Ubuntu touch working on not supported phones. [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2219740&highlight=ubuntu%20phone) is a guide for xperia phones.